# Breeding smaller humans

Tags: evolution, humans

Suppose in the future (about 3-4 decades in the future), we start preferring smaller people as mates. The average size of a human would go down, maybe as far as or further than average heights from the middle ages, peaking not far above 140cm. This would mean that everything could be made smaller to better suit these smaller humans and so it would be easier to house more of them, less resources and land would be needed to cater to and feed them, and so more resources could be put towards other things like space travel.

What effects could this have on the way society functions? - assuming the world is similar to what it is today, but with the obvious improvements in technology. Could it lead to far larger populations that use up the same space as before? - or would it be a big step forward for the progress and advancement of the species?

Comment: Some men may prefer petite women, but by and large women prefer tall men... Plus in _all_ populations around the world better lifestyle and lack of malnutrition has historically resulted in taller people. The [Human height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_height) article on Wikipedia is an eye opener.

Comment: Medieval folks were not 1m40 tall and about as tall as we are now. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-457506/Myth-debunked-Our-medieval-ancestors-just-tall-says-new-study.html http://researchnews.osu.edu/archive/medimen.htm

Comment: It has happened repeatedly and independently in modern human evolution (both African pygmies and various non-African negrito populations), mostly as an adaptation to unfavorable jungle environments.

Comment: Well could you maybe take what you know from that and put it in an answer related to my given premise?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer it would have very little effect other than requiring the resizing of tools and buildings. people might live slightly longer but the effect is minor. land use would be the same, you could build houses shorter but the floor area would be the same.

Comment: But surely if humans are smaller, everything could be scaled down in both directions. A short human isn't a squashed tall human, so the horizontal space used is less too. A smaller human has fewer cells to feed as they are smaller, so one would expect they'd need less food, so you need less farmland, so land use is reduced. Say people eat 20% less food. You now have 20% of all previous farmland to use for other things, which is a lot of land.

Comment: smaller organisms need more food per unit body mass, they burn through it more quickly. (this is actually one reasons being big is advantage) the total is not going to change much, although keep in mind we make far more food than we actually consume anyway. And humans are much taller than they are wide, so you really don't gain that much in terms of horizontal space. And keep in mind human proportions change with height as well. You can look at housing for little people for comparison.

Comment: I'm not saying you won't gain anything, but it's not going to be terribly noticeable.

Comment: Ok, say no horizontal space is gained. Let's also say that height drops 50% as a nice number (it will definitely be less than that). You can now fit almost double the floors in a building of a given height, twice as many people can live in the same space, technology improves so buildings get taller, more people live in smaller areas, more land is freed up. What is the effect? That is my question, and so far, people seem unable to answer it.

Comment: Oh the effect of freeing up land pretty minimal, we are not desperate for land. And you have to consider with smaller size their labor output will be smaller as well, how much soil can a 140cm person shift with a shovel. livestock might be a problem too, especially plow animals. I image domesticating cattle is much harder when you are that small.

Comment: you are not really freeing up land as much as letting cities get a little bit denser, and that is not going to come into play to much until late in history.  Like I said we are not super desperate for buildable land.

Comment: The points about physical labour and plough animals are completely irrelevant. This will be in the future, after the change in size has happened. If you want to move soil, use a digger.

Comment: right yes the plough is irrelevant, but not necessarily the physical labor, a huge number of jobs still have a bottleneck of human labor, your people are really going to have to invest in robotics and mechanization to make up the difference. especially for things that revolve around another organism, like lumberjacking, fishing, ranching, ect.

Comment: There exist many drive-able machines for forestry and fishing. There also exist plenty of tools to aid in physical labour such that the less able will be able to complete tasks like heavy lifting - examples are the dolly cart and the pulley or the A-frame.

But this is all irrelevant. My question is not about how much land is saved, but about how society may change based on this development. Having more or less or the same room doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: it really does, becasue society won't have much reason to change, there's not much change in land use, there's a increase in automation but you expect society to do that anyway, you're just not changing anything important.

Comment: Here's a reason to change: Culture. There have been reasons to prefer shorter women, stronger women, fatter people, skinnier people. Why is preferring shorter people suddenly not valid if all the others are? Fashion makes people do some extremely stupid things sometimes, so it may be a fashion trend that people breed with shorter people to produce "fashionably short" offspring. Pick one, there are hundreds of potential reasons why this might happen, but this reason is again irrelevant because a hypothetical reason is presumed and the question is about the outcome, not the cause. Try again.

Comment: I mean there is not much reason for Society to change just becasue height does.

Answer (score 1):

Evolution does not work like you imagine.

On average, all women get pregnant, wether they're good-looking or not (by whatever standard). And unless we change the usual human long-term relationship standard to a shimpanzee-style "the boss gets all the girls", also many males of the species get to be fathers. It'd take a *long* time for that to have a distinct, measureable effect.

Powerful evolutionary pressure occurs when a change of some characteristic results in a better survival rate of the offspring. On a small island, smaller people run a smaller risk of starving, without the drawback of being easy prey, because there are likely no large predators.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: No it doesn't. I'm pointing out the shortcomings in your question. ;-)

Comment: Except you aren't. You only appear to state that such a process would take a very long time. I at no point started out with a time frame at all. Of course it would take a long period of time to have a measurable effect, so my question was about what effect the smaller humans would have after becoming smaller over time.

Comment: And how on earth has this got 2 votes? It adds no directly relevant information. You are just saying it takes a long time (which ultimately has no effect on the premise I am putting forward) and the most basic point of evolution. Evolution may have been a bad tag, but selective breeding wasn't available. That definitely has very dramatic effects over a much shorter period of time. The source is dogs.